# Ways to cross out $n^2/2$ squares on a $n\times n$ chessboard

Tags: recreational-mathematics, chessboard

How many patterns $P_n$ are there to cross out $n^2/2$ squares on a $n\times n$ chessboard, so that the number of crossed out squares in each row and each column are all even?

Is there a way to get a general formula for $P_n$? Or, at least, a formula when $n$ is big?

For example, if $n = 4$, the answer could be found as $ P_4 = 246$ by listing all probabilities

[image]

Comment: If $n-1$ rows are even, so is the $n^{th}$, and the same with columns, so a coarse estimate might be $2^{-(2n-2)}$

Comment: @Empy2 sorry there's something wrong in my first narration, i've just updated the question.

Comment: I don't see where the random aspect comes in?

Comment: @joriki yeah you are right, I deleted “randomly”

Comment: @joriki The post originally asked about the probability that crossing out $n^2/2$ random squares resulted in each row and each column having an even number of crosses. When it was first rephrased the overhaul wasn't complete.